# Code to copy named ranges to PPT, where named ranges are variable

Tags: excel, vba, powerpoint, copy-paste

I have a working code that will copy named ranges from a specific sheet on excel and then paste them to a specific sheet on powerpoint. However, it is not working exactly how I need it to.

The main issue is that I could have between 1 and 20 named ranges, based on the data in my workbook, so if I list all of the named ranges, then I get an error on the lines where these named ranges do not exist.

The code I am using is:

```
Sub copytablestoppt()
    Dim powerpointapp As Object
    Set powerpointapp = CreateObject("powerpoint.application")

    Dim destinationPPT As String
    destinationPPT = ("J:xxx\CPA1.ppt")

    On Error GoTo ERR_PPOPEN
    Dim mypresentation As Object
    Set mypresentation = powerpointapp.Presentations.Open(destinationPPT)
    On Error GoTo 0

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False

    PasteToSlide mypresentation.Slides(3), Worksheets("Start").Range("DataP")
    PasteToSlide mypresentation.Slides(52), Worksheets("Start").Range("IMEI")
    PasteToSlide mypresentation.Slides(4), Worksheets("Top Cell IDs & Top Contacts").Range("TopCellIDs1")

    powerpointapp.Visible = True
    powerpointapp.Activate

    Application.CutCopyMode = False

ERR_PPOPEN:
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    If Err.Number <> 0 Then
        MsgBox "Failed to open " & destinationPPT, vbCritical
    End If
End Sub


Private Sub PasteToSlide(mySlide As Object, rng As Range)
    rng.Copy
    mySlide.Shapes.PasteSpecial DataType:=2

    Dim myShape As Object
    Set myShape = mySlide.Shapes(mySlide.Shapes.Count)

    myShape.Left = 278
    myShape.Top = 175

End Sub
```

Does anyone have any ideas how to work around the error when my range does not exist?

Comment: There are several places in your code where you could usefully use a Try function.  https://rubberduckvba.wordpress.com/2019/05/09/pattern-tryparse/

Answer (score 1):

Check if the named range exists before copying. If it exists, then only copy it.

```
Dim rng As Range

On Error Resume Next
Set rng = Worksheets("Start").Range("DataP")
On Error GoTo 0

If Not rng Is Nothing Then
    PasteToSlide mypresentation.Slides(3), Worksheets("Start").Range("DataP")
End If
```

**Important Note:** If you are planning to use the above approach then always ensure that you add this line from 2nd named range onwards.

```
Set rng = Nothing '<~~~ 

On Error Resume Next
Set rng = Worksheets("Start").Range("IMEI")
On Error GoTo 0
```